# what is use of UIGestureRecognizer and diffrence between UITouch and UIGestureRecoginzer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friends i'm new in iphone so i cant understand the UIGestureRecoginzer. if someone know the answer means pls help me and UITouch also......

UITapGestureRecognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can write everything one of the defined UIGestureRecognizer does in UITouch code, but it will be complex and probably buggy, so you have access to some of the most commonly used gestures for free.

A good start is the [Apple Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1), explaining the difference and the applications of both methods.

Comment: post some sample coding...or link

Comment: quoting from your link helps because links can die or page can changed